# how to get version number or something else into my zip archive in gradle

Tags: gradle

EDIT:
I am trying to run these two commands and get these results in a gradle subproject...

```
gradle assemble -> databus-Developer-Build.zip
gradle -DmyVersion=1.0.2 -> databus-1.0.2.zip
```

Currently, my output is databus-null.zip IF I use $version instead of $myVersion.  When using $MyVersion, I get the error "myVersion is not a property on that task".  :( :(.

**EDIT**

So, trying out the first answer completely failed with "Could not find property $myVersion on task ':webserver:myZip"

NOTE: I am trying to do this in a subproject right now.  Here is the subproject gradle code...

```
project(':webserver') {
    project.ext.genLibDir = file('lib')
    project.ext.fixedLibDir = file('../master/libother')

    dependencies {    
        compile project(':master')
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/play-1.2.4/framework', include: 'play-*.jar')   
    }

    task deleteJars(type: Delete) {
        ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
        delete ext.collection
    }
    task copyJars(type: Copy) { 
        from(configurations.compile) {}
        from(fixedLibDir) {}
        into genLibDir
    }
    copyJars.dependsOn('deleteJars')
    classes.dependsOn('copyJars')

    task myZip(type: Zip) {
        archiveName "dashboard-"+$myVersion+".zip"
        from('..') {
            include 'webserver/run*.sh'
            include 'webserver/app/**'
            include 'webserver/conf/**'
            include 'webserver/play-1.2.4/**'
            include 'webserver/public/**'
        }
    }

    assemble.dependsOn('myZip')

    //playframework has it's own generation of .classpath and .project fils so do not 
    //overwrite their versions.  NEED to call "play.bat eclipsify" here...
    task eclipse(overwrite: true) {
    }


    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
        if (taskGraph.hasTask(assemble) && myVersion == null) {
            myVersion = 'Developer-Build'
        }
    }
}
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your question?

Comment: How to get "databus-"+$myVersion+".zip" to create the file databus-1.0.5.zip is my question.  Right now, it creates databus-null.zip on the filesystem.  I followed the example with only one twist in that it is my subproject that needs that version number.

Comment: oh, and you can run our assemble like this "gradle -DmyVersion=1.0.2 assemble"  or "gradle assemble" where one ends up with databus-1.0.2.zip and the other ends up with databus-Developer-Build.zip

Comment: hmmm, this has something to do with the phases again...boy that has been screwing me up forever...but how to get zip done in the execution phase so it can read the property...at least I think that is the reason. (and hopefully not lose the checks it does on if it needs to zip or skip the zip as it is up to date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the correct answer is doing something like this...(add this to allprojects section)..

```
   if (project.hasProperty('myVersion')) {
     project.ext.xVersion = project.myVersion
   } else {
     project.ext.xVersion = 'Developer-Build'
   }
```

and interestingly enough this below one does NOT work because 'version' seems to be some sort of reserverd property and is set to unspecified on startup...

```
   if (project.hasProperty('version')) {
     project.ext.xVersion = project.version
   } else {
     project.ext.xVersion = 'Developer-Build'
   }
```

Seeing as version seems to be a reserved property, it is most likely used in publishing artifacts so the best solution then maybe the following

```
   if (project.hasProperty('myVersion')) {
     project.version = project.myVersion
   } else {
     project.version = 'Developer-Build'
   }
```

and the automated build passes in myVersion and developers of course don't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that you get the error "myVersion is not a property on that task" is, that you have to pass the property with -P instead of "-D"